# Converting to single channel image in OpenCV

Tags: visual-studio-2008, image-processing, opencv, runtime-error

i'm working with openCV and i'm trying to convert an image into a single channel image.
i loaded the image with:
`IplImage* img=cvLoadImage(“abc.pbm”);`
i wasnt sure how i was supposed to convert to single channel so i used:

`IplImage* temp = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img->depth, 1);
cvSetImageCOI(img, 1);
cvCopy(img, temp);`

it compiles fine, but it crashes during runtime saying  "opencv error: assertion failed (src.channels()==dst.channels()) in unknown function ..."

can anyone help me out??
can i get any better suggestions to convert to single channel image?

Answer (score 4):

you could also load it as greyscale:

```
IplImage* img=cvLoadImage(“abc.pbm”,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`cvCvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvcvtcolor#void%20cvCvtColor%28const%20CvArr*%20src,%20CvArr*%20dst,%20int%20code%29).